# How to determine the fully qualified tablenames of aliased tables, when a specifically named column is used in a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, metadata

suppose StoredProcedure1 (SP1) contains the following

```
SELECT 
      A.COL1
     ,A.COL2
     ,B.COL2
     ,C.COL5
    FROM MYBIGTABLE A 
    INNER JOIN MYSMALLTABLE B ON A.IDCOL  = B.IDCOL
    INNER JOIN MYOTHERTABLE C ON B.ID2COL = C.IDCOL
```

Suppose I want to know about all such stored procedures that contain columns called **COL2**

I realise that I can query the stored procedure definitions in metadata tables and that will return 'SP1' as a result, but how then to return the fully qualified 'MYBIGTABLE' AND 'MYSMALLTABLE' as rows?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of DMVs for this. My guess is that sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities can be useful:

```
USE Adventureworks
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.myProc
AS
SELECT h.AccountNumber, d.LineTotal
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS d
 INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS h ON d.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID  
WHERE 1 = 0
GO

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.myProc', 'OBJECT')

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities('Sales.SalesOrderDetail', 'OBJECT')
```

Comment: Never knew about this DMV before, +1.

Comment: Not sure I follow. You're just using those views to show objects upon which the proc depends. How can that be used to expand out if particular columns are used, which was my original question?

Comment: In your code example, I would be using e.g. "accountNumber" as an input and the output would be "SalesOrderHeader" for "myProc"

Comment: Ah I see. You want to input a column name and as ouput get the objects that refer to this column name. I don't believe that these DMV will do that for you, so you are probably left with reading the source code for your objects and take it from these. OBJECT_DEFINITION() might be helpful for this.